# Website for finding most popular/active library

Tags: web-apps, web

I need/want a website that can tell me the relative popularity/activity of libraries (and possibly tools) in the same problem domain.

For instance: I'm trying to find a C++ networking library that is well supported. The problem is: *there are so many of them!*, which one is the more popular one?

My reasoning is that the more popular/active library is more likely to be better supported, of higher quality and overall 'healthier' than the lesser popular one. (Group intelligence, anyone?)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that website recommendations are off-topic here (see: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/191/185)). Unfortunately, that topic is not covered by any SE site currently.

Comment: Some argue that this question might be off-topic. However, I still think this question adds value to the Software Recommendations stackexchange in that it is a 'meta' question, it should allow people to be more self-reliant.

Comment: Xunie, I asked your question at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10014/popularity-of-programming-libraries while trying to make it on-topic there. Cheers!